# How to run Firestore server-side pessimistic lock transactions in a project using Dart

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, transactions, pessimistic-locking

I created a library in Dart based on the premise of running pessimistic lock transactions in the Firebase server client library, but I found that the Firebase Admin SDK required to run it does not support Dart.

And I found a library called Dartfire to use the Firebase Admin SDK with Dart, but as far as I could tell, server-side pessimistic lock transaction of Firestore seemed to be outside the scope of the support.(There's a possibility I'm wrong.)

For the Cloud Firestore REST API, I couldn't find any documentation that mentions server-side pessimistic locking.

Is there any way to use transactions with server-side pessimistic locks in a way that makes use of the library I have already created with Dart?

Or do I have to rewrite it all in another language that is supported by Firebase Admin SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [RPC API docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rpc) here, I'd expect that:

- the admin endpoints use pessimistic locking and
- the non-admin endpoints use optimistic locking

From [searching the code](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Acachapa%2Ffiredart+v1&type=code), it seems that Firedart uses the non-admin endpoints - so indeed will use optimistic locking.

A quick further search of the RPCAPI docs for the [Admin RPC endpoint](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rpc/google.firestore.admin.v1) confirms that it defaults to pessimistic locking for transactions, but also shows that you can specify the [concurrency mode](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rpc/google.firestore.admin.v1#concurrencymode).

Since you're using Firedart, it seems that you're bound to optimistic locking. Considering [filing a feature request](https://github.com/cachapa/firedart/issues) (or even better: a PR) for adding admin bindings (as an option) to Firedart.